# How to type a configurable factory function in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, factory

I'm trying to get a basic example working for a factory function that returns various return types depending on the `key` string that it passed to it…

```
const factory = <
    T extends Record<string, () => any>,
    K extends keyof T
>(options: T) => {
    return (key: K): ReturnType<T[K]> => {
        return options[key]()
    }
}

const create = factory({
    string: () => 'A string of text.',
    number: () => 42,
    boolean: () => true
})

const s = create('string')
const n = create('number')
const b = create('boolean')
```

But in this case `s`, `n`, and `b` all have a type of `string | number | boolean`. Instead of each one having the narrowest type possible. ([TypeScript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMwIYhmATgTzgXjgHmDmLgBU4BTADxgogBMo4AlC8de-WdASwgHMANHAAUASlwA+OEgiZJgoiQDSlGnUZwA1hUxgEZYJJFgADjB6QoALjISc0gN5Li6CjACu6CKJ2ZbymK2rJ7epJimFPikANrKALrSDnDOJGlwbqE+ZhZWMX7x4i5wAL7AZaBW8CBuSLS4iChoWCKpJNx8-LbiUnAA5ACCcB0CcPpwtDQAdH2KaRAeALYARhTo3fbSACwATHMky2BgADYUshu9MOgeFOViwJXQ8Ex4NWe0In0j-H334E9wHyvWofPoLFZrX6PWBwZYNN51CifQ4nM4QKFAA))

How can I make the narrowing work?

Comment: Move the `K` generic from the outer function to the function it returns.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Could you explain why that works? (Also if you want to put it as an answer I'm happy to accept it.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a generic function, its type parameters are specified at that time.  This is either done manually by the caller using angle brackets (e.g., `factory<MyType, MyKey>(someValueOfMyType)`), or the compiler infers them from the parameters passed to the function and context in which the function is called.  With your definition, the call to

```
const create = factory({
    string: () => 'A string of text.',
    number: () => 42,
    boolean: () => true
});
```

has to infer `T` and `K`.  `T` is easy to infer because the parameter passed into `create` is of type `T`.  So `T` is `{string: ()=>string, number: ()=>number, boolean: ()=>boolean}`.  But there is nowhere in that call where `K` can be inferred.  There is no parameter of type `K`, and the context is just saving the return value to a variable named `create`.  Thus the inference fails.  In such cases, the compiler picks the widest type that works, namely its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  That means `K` is inferred as `keyof T` which becomes `"string" | "number" | "boolean"`.  And therefore `create` has the type

```
// const create: (key: "string" | "number" | "boolean") => string | number | boolean
```

which you don't want.

---

You really only want `T` to be specified when you call `factory()`, and you don't want `K` to be specified until you call `create()`.  For example,  once you call `create("string")`, then you know that `K` should be `"string"`.  And since generic function type parameters are specified when you call the function, you want `create()` itself to be a generic function where `K` is its type parameter.

So the solution here is to leave `T` where it is, but move the `K` generic from the outer function to the function it returns:

```
const factory = <
    T extends Record<string, () => any>>(options: T) => {
    return <K extends keyof T>(key: K): ReturnType<T[K]> => {
        return options[key]()
    }
}
```

Now when you call `factory()` it returns a generic function:

```
const create = factory({
    string: () => 'A string of text.',
    number: () => 42,
    boolean: () => true
})

/* const create: <K extends "string" | "number" | "boolean">(key: K) => ReturnType<{
    string: () => string;
    number: () => number;
    boolean: () => boolean;
}[K]> */
```

And then it behaves as you intend:

```
const s = create('string') // string
const n = create('number') // number
const b = create('boolean') // boolean
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=34&ssc=9&pln=30&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwCYDEHCiATgTxgXhgB4AoGcmAFRgFMAPKGsJCGAJRtCySOiwEswAcwA0MABQBKAgD4YCMDhliA0rQZMWMANY0cIAGZUZ4kAAco-cBABcVafjkBvMhSw0oAVyxgJunHYqknYcXj6UOGY0RJQA2ioAunKOMC4U6TDuYb7mltax-glSruQAviTlJKCQsIhIAMLuCIwE8MhoGNg44mkUfIJCdlKyMADkAIIw-cIwhjCMDAB0oyIlMGCeALZwNFhDDnIALABMq+lwICAANjQK+yNQWJ40FZIA3CQA9J9UMIIGu3cSHkrCc00GEkkjnBYkWcNKq2+MDU-0BNGBCFYACJwViYAAfGBYjbbXZ4wlYi7XW5gLFfH7VaBtBpNRhDfx2HGPAbkokknZYXmUy43BRYg5TbkzQn83YE+AimkkZWM2AGdCYXCtUjpaj0RjMVgcLg8GGQkYKJQmXJWSB2SgS3rkLLeXxENT6zSsfxzSgmDnI4LsDyuiJRGLxJIjJ0ZF0+WYWW0QAp6IqSNblSqqmDAVk0Vrqzq4HprcH3FITSUCGZzBZQZZnCiyvbmlInRvkKmisDluSPZ6vL4AKhz1lgudubOIHo0hqJuPlxK2AqFXZpWP9ekCEtCoci0RjZdbcnBH3Szd762XuzPFDXd2PCupCg+pUjciHnxVY6mrQnzRocRRnBUZpCRcEqh-XxCH-RggObUCYCRZtIJqeA-zzID7zARCkWwkggA)